# Ever Default Tagging - for Credit Risk Modelling- Python

Tags: python, pandas, modeling

I'm new to python and i faced some difficulty on writing this certain of codes. So to give a background, i want to do an ever-default tagging for credit risk modelling.

0 for non-default accounts and
1 for default accounts

So the idea/concept is that throughout the date performance ( of 12 months), if the specific customer (ID) ever has one event of default (1) then the next performance after that event (for that customer) will be tagged as a default (1) even though the 'default tagging' is 0.

so the input like this:

| ID | Date Performance | Default Tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2021-03-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-04-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-05-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-06-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-07-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-08-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-09-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-10-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-11-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-12-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2022-01-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2022-02-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-03-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-04-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-05-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-06-01 | 1 |
| ABB | 2021-07-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-08-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-09-01 | 1 |
| ABB | 2021-10-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-11-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-12-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2022-01-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2022-02-01 | 0 |

And the output would be on a new column like this:

| ID | Date Performance | Ever Default Tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2021-03-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-04-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-05-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-06-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-07-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-08-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-09-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-10-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-11-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2021-12-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2022-01-01 | 0 |
| AAA | 2022-02-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-03-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-04-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-05-01 | 0 |
| ABB | 2021-06-01 | 1 |
| ABB | 2021-07-01 | 1 |
| ABB | 2021-08-01 | 1 |
| ABB | 2021-09-01 | 1 |
| ABB | 2021-10-01 | 1 |
| ABB | 2021-11-01 | 1 |
| ABB | 2021-12-01 | 1 |
| ABB | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| ABB | 2022-02-01 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code to do what your question asks:

(**UPDATED** to replace one-line lambda with more readable function for `apply`, and also to correct an off-by-one error on when default begins.)

```py
import pandas as pd
records = [
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2021-03-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2021-04-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2021-05-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2021-06-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2021-07-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2021-08-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2021-09-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2021-10-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2021-11-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2021-12-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2022-01-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAA', 'Date Performance': '2022-02-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2021-03-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2021-04-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2021-05-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2021-06-01', 'Default Tag': 1},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2021-07-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2021-08-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2021-09-01', 'Default Tag': 1},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2021-10-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2021-11-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2021-12-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2022-01-01', 'Default Tag': 0},
    {'ID':'AAB', 'Date Performance': '2022-02-01', 'Default Tag': 0}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
def hasEverDefaulted(df, x):
    id, dt = 'ID', 'Date Performance'
    hasSameIdAndNotLaterDate = (df[id] == x[id]) & (df[dt] <= x[dt])
    return int(sum(df[hasSameIdAndNotLaterDate]['Default Tag']) > 0)
df['Default Tag'] = df.apply(lambda x: hasEverDefaulted(df, x), axis=1)
df.rename(columns={'Default Tag': 'Ever Default Tag'}, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     ID Date Performance  Ever Default Tag
0   AAA       2021-03-01                 0
1   AAA       2021-04-01                 0
2   AAA       2021-05-01                 0
3   AAA       2021-06-01                 0
4   AAA       2021-07-01                 0
5   AAA       2021-08-01                 0
6   AAA       2021-09-01                 0
7   AAA       2021-10-01                 0
8   AAA       2021-11-01                 0
9   AAA       2021-12-01                 0
10  AAA       2022-01-01                 0
11  AAA       2022-02-01                 0
12  AAB       2021-03-01                 0
13  AAB       2021-04-01                 0
14  AAB       2021-05-01                 0
15  AAB       2021-06-01                 1
16  AAB       2021-07-01                 1
17  AAB       2021-08-01                 1
18  AAB       2021-09-01                 1
19  AAB       2021-10-01                 1
20  AAB       2021-11-01                 1
21  AAB       2021-12-01                 1
22  AAB       2022-01-01                 1
23  AAB       2022-02-01                 1
```

**UPDATE #2**:
Here's an explanation of what's happening with the call to `apply()`.

When you call the `apply()` method of an object of type `DataFrame` in pandas with argument `axis=1`, it repeatedly calls a specified function for each row of the `DataFrame` object with a `Series` object that contains the values in the columns of the `DataFrame` object for the given row.

In the code in this answer, the function that gets called is a `lambda` with the given row as argument `x`, which in turn calls `hasEverDefaulted()` with arguments `df` and `x`.

Within `hasEverDefaulted()`, we do a vectorized logical calculation to obtain a column of `boolean` values which scan the entire `'ID'` column of `df` checking for equality with the `'ID'` value in row `x` and also scan the entire `'Date Performance'` column checking for date values that are `<=` the date value in row `x`. We then use the vectorized logical "and" operator `&` to combine these and select (by setting the result row corresponding to `x` to `True`) only values which match the current row's "id" and also have a "date" that is no later than that of the current row. We assign this vectorized (columnar) result to the variable `hasSameIdAndNotLaterDate`.

We then use this variable as a `boolean` filter to select from `df` only the rows that are `True`, and we sum the `Default Tag` column values for these rows, create a `boolean` value by testing this sum to check if it's `> 0` (in which case default has occurred for that row's `'ID'` on or before that row's `'Date Performance'`) and return an `int` version of this `boolean` value (namely, `0` or `1`).

Back in the statement that calls `apply()` we assign the columnar result of `apply()` to the `'Default Tag'` column of `df`. To make it clear that we have now changed the semantics of this column (which now indicates whether default occurred on or before the `'Date Performance'` date in each row), we call the `rename()` method of the `DataFrame` object `df` to change the column name to `'Ever Default Tag'`.

Comment: Hello, I've tried on my real dataset and it works, perhaps can you explain to me more on this part of code? `hasSameIdAndNotLaterDate = (df[id] == x[id]) & (df[dt] <= x[dt])`,

Comment: @Bagus Sure - please see the detailed explanation in the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
for id in df['ID'].unique():
  try:
    df.loc[df['ID']==id,['Ever Default Tag']] = 0
    index_value = list(df[(df['ID']==id)&(df['Default Tag']==1)].index)[0]
    df.loc[index_value:,['Ever Default Tag']] = 1
  except:
    continue
df['Ever Default Tag'] = df['Ever Default Tag'].astype(int)
```